# Where can I find lncRNA expression data for different cell types?

Tags: public-databases, ucsc

Are there any publicly available databases providing expression data for long non-coding RNAs (lncRNAs) across cell types of multicellular organisms? Alternatively, are there lesser known [UCSC](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgGateway) tracks for this?

- **Example 1:** I want to compare tissue-specific expression of the human lncRNA *Xist* across HeLa, GM12878, and HEK293 cell types [or
  more].
- **Example 2:** I want to compare tissue-specific expression of the plant lncRNA *COLDAIR* across cortex, phloem, and trichoblast cell
  types [or more].

Answer (score 2):

As long as the lncRNA is annotated you can use https://gtexportal.org/home/gene.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a fantastic resource for comparing lncRNA expression (or *any annotated gene* expression) across **primary, non-diseased human tissues**! Thanks for sharing, Mary. 
Hopefully similar portals/databases will be developed in the near future for other multicellular organisms [and maybe even for cell lines?!].